# Why is find looking in the current directory?

Tags: find

I have a bash script `/var/www/scripts/process_sounds.sh` that uses the command:

```
find /var/www/unprocessed_sounds/ * -type f
```

It's supposed to find all the files in the `unprocessed_sounds` directory, which it does, but it also find all the files in the scripts directory (and then processes them like sound files, which is not what I want).

Why would `find` return things in the current directory?

Comment: Incidentally, if you actually wanted a wildcard match for something, you could do `-name '*'`, but it only would make sense if it were something other than *.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are writing the command in the wrong way. To search for file in `/var/www/unprocessed_sounds/` directory, you should just write like this

```
find /var/www/unprocessed_sounds/ -type f
```

Writing like `find /var/www/unprocessed_sounds/ * -type f` will search for file in `/var/www/unprocessed_sounds/` and `*` which means all directories in current directory also.

Answer (score 2):

you have a space in your command

```
find /var/www/unprocessed_sounds/ * -type f
```

`find` is interpreting that you want to look for all files in `/var/www/unprocessed_sounds/` AND `./*`  take the star away (as find will dig into the directory anyway)

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to process the files in the /var/www/unprocessed_sounds/ directory, then you don't need to use the * in there.

Try to only use:

```
find /var/www/unprocessed_sounds/ -type f
```